# Minicart content doesnt appear 1.9 (bakerop)

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery, mini-cart

http://picknickbankspecialist.nl/

As you can see at the top the dropdown is only showing the animation, but no content.

**minicart.phtml**

```
    $cart_summary_qty = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getSummaryQty();
$cart_summary_qty = !empty($cart_summary_qty)?$cart_summary_qty:0;
$cart_subtotal = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
$cart_subtotal = Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice( $cart_subtotal );

$cart_total = Mage::helper("ves_tempcp")->__("%s");
$cart_total = sprintf($cart_total, $cart_summary_qty, $cart_subtotal);
?>
<div id="cart" class="block-content dropdown clearfix">
    <div class="heading">
        <div class="cart-inner">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="shopping-cart-icon"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> </a>
            <h4 class="hidden-xs">
                <a href="javascript:;"><?php echo $this->__('Shopping Bag ') ?> -
                    <span id="cart-total"><?php echo $cart_total ." ITEM "; ?></span>
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>

                </a>
            </h4>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content"> This part seems to be not loading
       <?php echo Mage::helper("ves_tempcp/framework")->getMinicartBlock(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 text_confirm_delete_item = "<?php echo $this->__('Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?'); ?>";
 var text_cart_total = "%total% <?php echo $this->__('ITEM'); ?>";
</script>
```

**PAGE.XML**

```
<block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="venus.minicart" as="venusMinicart" template="page/html/minicart.phtml"/>
```

**DEFAULT.phtml (header)**

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-4">
    <div class="cart-top pull-right">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('venusMinicart'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am quite stuck on this since the installation is a mess, anyone that has some ideas what is going wrong here?

extras: **cartcontroller**

```
<?php

class Ves_Tempcp_MinicartController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction(){
        $this->loadLayout();

        if(($minicart_head = $this->getLayout()->getBlock("minicart_head")) && !Mage::registry('minicart_head')) {
            Mage::register('minicart_head', $minicart_head );
        }
        $json = array();
        $json['html'] =  Mage::helper("ves_tempcp/framework")->getMinicartHtml();
        $json['summary_qty'] = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getSummaryQty();
        $json['summary_qty'] = !empty($json['summary_qty'])?$json['summary_qty']:0;
        $json['subtotal'] = Mage::helper('ves_tempcp')->getCartSubtotal();

        echo Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode( $json );

    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so i completely deleted the minicart.phtml and used one of another custom theme, did the trick in the "hack" kinda way but i guess for now its fine.

Hopefully someone still notices something wrong in my minicart.phtml so i wont have to .css that stuff myself!

Comment: As you can already guess, i am such a professional developer.